# Creating Dynamic Variable using dynamic data from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-variables

I am a newbie to programming and here too.

```
$sqlb="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name3 WHERE Batch=$batch AND Bcode=$bcode AND Regulation   
='$regulation' AND Year='$yval' and Sem='$sval' GROUP BY Smallsubname order by Subcode 
ASC";

$resultb=mysql_query($sqlb);
$countb=mysql_num_rows($resultb);
while($rowsb=mysql_fetch_array($resultb))
{
    $ssn=$rowsb['Smallsubname'];
    $scode=$rowsb['Subcode'];
    echo "$ssn";
}

enter code here
```

I need help to assign multiple variables to multiple `scode`s automatically, because sometimes the number of `scode`s will differ due to branch and year also. So please help me how to create the variable dynamically. And I have to create some arrays also. How to create them dynamically? And please provide the information with perfect code because I am very newbie to programming also. So please don't use technical terms, only code.

Answer (score 0):

This should helps you:

```
$sqlb="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name3 WHERE Batch=$batch AND Bcode=$bcode AND Regulation   
='$regulation' AND Year='$yval' and Sem='$sval' GROUP BY Smallsubname order by Subcode 
ASC";

$resultb=mysql_query($sqlb);
$countb=mysql_num_rows($resultb);

$scodes = array();  // new empty array for scode
$ssns = array();    // array for ssn
$i = 0;             // last position

while($rowsb=mysql_fetch_array($resultb))
{
    $ssn=$rowsb['Smallsubname'];
    //$scode=$rowsb['Subcode'];

$ssns[$i] = $rowsb['Smallsubname'];
$scodes[$i] = $rowsb['Subcode'];

    echo "$ssn";

$i += 1; // increments position
}
```

Comment: will try this and give feed back, after that i have to assign so many arrays automatically, i will ask abt tht later,  Thnx for early reply